# how to get the html of the content of a cross-domain iframe, or how to get html from another domain by other ways?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to replace a cross domain iframe with the html it contains.
I can add html and javascript to both domains.
I know this should be possible, since youtube seems to do something similar with the comment section.
I would just need to do the same.
If nothing else works, could this also be done using 'postMessage'?
or I could use something like 'document.domain'?

...
okay, since the site didnt let me post the question, I have to write something more I guess.
I need this because I have to create a script to auto-load youtube comments, since they dont load at ALL on older browsers. I tried using iframes to embed the same thing youtube originally does. But since the content is retrieved from apis.google.com, I had a lot of trouble trying to make it resize itself like it should be. A lot of solutions seem to not work on older browsers, but thats why I need this in the first place. I noticed in firebug how the comments dont seem to open in an iframe, even though I was sure they did. I could even open the frame itself sometime ago, thats how I got the URL the comments are called from. Now only that site's html can be seen there, embedded inside the container.
I would be grateful if anyone finally gave a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [YouTube Comments API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments) which returns sets of `author`, `title`, and `content` for a video. I believe you are free to stylize this information however you want.

If you insist on working with iframes then this may be a duplicate of : [Cross domain iframe content load detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754282/cross-domain-iframe-content-load-detection?rq=1)

Comment: thats not what i want. i need to paste the content of the iframe on the site. i need the parent site to somehow get the html content of the frame. or just resize the frame somehow dynamically