# NW JS window loaded doesnt trigger for a URL but does from a local file

Tags: javascript, nw.js

I'm trying to get the loaded event on a live web page but it doesn't fire like a local page.

So the loaded never fires with this:

```
var mywin = nw.Window.open('http://www.google.com', {"frame": false}, function(testWin) {
    testWin.on('loaded', function() {
        alert("testWin loaded");
        testWin.moveTo(0, 0);
    });
});
```

but always fires with this:

```
nw.Window.open('test.html', {"frame": false}, function(testWin) {
    testWin.on('loaded', function() {
        alert("testWin loaded");
        testWin.moveTo(0, 0);
    });
});
```

only difference is the local file or URL.

Thanks and sorry for the dumb question (I'm not a programmer so I'm sure its something really basic).

I'm using NW JS 13.2

Regards
Andrew

Comment: why "loaded" event fire multiple time whenever my iframe loaded inside this window

Answer (score 0):

JS crossdomain security policies. The only accessible attribute of `window` with domain, that differs from your current (the domain where your script is running) is `location`, as far as I know.

You should probably look into this [Cross domain iframe content load detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754282/cross-domain-iframe-content-load-detection) to see, if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks Haldagan, I would have thought that NWJS was capable of knowing about what's happening within chrome given the nature of node webkit.