# Load another domain website in a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I want to load another website on my website using the iframe.

I have seen some other issues while loading using the iframe in some other websites.
**So can't we implement iframe to load other domain website pages? If so, do we have another way to load the websites**?

**The following is the way I tested**:

I have tried in 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe with the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues" width="800" height="800">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**I got the following error.**
Refused to display 'https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754282/cross-domain-iframe-content-load-detection

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is NO, you cannot embed this site using iFrame.

If the site allowed it, your code is fine - however in this case you do not have a valid way to embed this site.

> [The frame-ancestors  directive specifies valid parents that may embed a page using the `<frame>` and `<iframe>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors)

Obviously they do not WANT you to embed their site:

> The look and feel of the Service is copyright © GitHub, Inc. All rights reserved. You may not duplicate, copy, or reuse any portion of the HTML/CSS, Javascript, or visual design elements or concepts without express written permission from GitHub.

---

**HOWEVER**

You can use javascript to get the content since [their API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) allows you to do so.

Try ajaxing to https://api.github.com/repos/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues - I see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` so you are able to return that in an Ajax response to your page

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("https://api.github.com/repos/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues",function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $("#result").html(data[0].title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

or write a proxy on your own server using

```
curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues"
```

Comment: Can we get the data using jquery and then load the content in iframe? Is there any trick?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you give little more details or the references?

Comment: Is frame-ancestors 'self' also meaning the same?

Comment: That means the site will allow itself to embed its own content

Answer (score 0):

You **can** put a page from another origin in an iframe **if** that page allows it. That one doesn't, it uses the [Content Security Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/) to tell the browser it's not okay via the [`frame-ancestors`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-ancestors) policy:

> The `frame-ancestors` directive indicates whether the user agent should allow embedding the resource using a `frame`, `iframe`, `object`, `embed` or `applet` element, or equivalent functionality in non-HTML resources. Resources can use this directive to avoid many UI Redressing [UIREDRESS] attacks by avoiding being embedded into potentially hostile contexts.

Comment: Can we get the data using jquery and then load the content in iframe? Is there any trick?

Comment: @JeevaJsb: Almost certainly not, because if they're doing this, they will also use the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to prevent your origin from accessing their content via ajax. You *could* make a request for it to your own server, have your server request it from theirs, and then return it to your page. I would respectfully suggest that as they very clearly do not want their content used in this way, that you not use their content in this way.

Comment: Seems we are duplicating the answers and comments here

Comment: I thought the comment notification will not send to him. I want him opinion too. So I commented the same here.

Comment: To be fair, they may only use this option to protect against click-jacking-type attacks, which is what this feature is mainly for preventing.

Comment: Funny how we post 30 seconds apart

Comment: @mplungjan: Happens all the time. Took me a few to find the spec, it's not on my normal reference list.