# AWS apigateway and iframe tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have set up a simple website using the AWS apigateway with a Lambda function back-end.

The apigateway is set up to return 'text/html' Content-Type which has been working absolutely fine.

My latest development has been to add some "iframe" tags to the site to embed content from another (non amazon) domain.

Now, when the page is rendered in the browser the content referenced by the iframe is not displayed. Yet, when I save the html locally and open it in a browser, the iframe content is displayed as it should - this proves that the html code is fine.

Is there some kind of security that AWS have in place to block embedded content from other domains? If so, what do i need to change to allow this?

Comment: Iframes are loaded by the browser. Your browser loads HTML, sees an iframe tag, and then interacts with the server that the iframe is pointing to. AWS isn't blocking anything. My guess is the server you are trying to load iframe content from is blocking it, similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068019/load-another-domain-website-in-a-iframe You need to open your browser's developer tools console and get the actual error or warning message in order to track down what the exact issue is.

Comment: Yes.It looks like its the cross origin security in the browser that is preventing the embedded content.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: I have tried to work round this by setting the following headers in the response from the apigateway:

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*' 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'

I can see that the headers are set correctly in the response when i run Firefox in Dev mode but the iframe is still not displayed.
Any ideas of how i can resolve this (on the server side) ?

Comment: The server serving the iframe content needs to set those headers.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Is that really the case? That does not make sense to me. By setting those headers in the apigateway I am allowing content from another domain to be embedded. I dont have any control over the other domain to set those headers. I have set up a mock service in the apigateway to demonstrate the issue: https://j9crd7qmbd.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/

Comment: It sounds like those headers weren't the issue, but you are thinking incorrectly about how those headers work. The headers don't say "you can embed stuff inside my content". What the headers say is "this content can be embedded in other content". That's why the other server would have to set those headers, if that was the issue. The headers are a mechanism to prevent other people from embedding your website content inside some other website without your authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was that the embedded link was using http but the page being served by the apigateway was using https.

The Mozilla docs refer this as "Mixed content". Fortunately the site which i am embedding from also offers the same site over https so i have just amended the URL to use this.

Thanks for your help