# hide iframe if it caught by CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've few third party urls to load in my local iframe. For few urls frame is able to load the content but few it is failing with cross origin domain policy. I tried with `.load`, `iframe.error` , `onerror`, Nothing is triggered on error. I've seen few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754282/cross-domain-iframe-content-load-detection). But doesn't seem to be helpful. Is there any workable solution on this ?

Comment: One possible approach, is to try to load the URL with ajax get request first. If it is a success and data size is greater then 0, then you proceed to opening an iframe for given url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is also not helping either :-(