# Onload event does not trigger

Tags: javascript

I want to send some data via `postMessage` from a page to another one which have `different domains`. However, I cannot achieve that since the code inside `$(yo.document).load` never runs; I tried the commented version as well. Here is my code:

```
<a onclick="popupCenter('http://localhost:58810');" href="javascript:void(0);">CLICK</a>
<script>

    function popupCenter(url) {
        const yo = window.open(url);
        $(yo.document).load(function() {
        //yo.document.onload = function() {
            console.log("yo loaded");
            yo.postMessage("Hello mate", "*");
        });
    } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The new window opens normally, however the callback inside `load` is not called. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting when Iframe content has loaded (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751435/detecting-when-iframe-content-has-loaded-cross-browser)

Comment: I don’t think you can attach a load event handler to an iframe cross-domain ... However, if only the port differs, you could perhaps get away with setting `document.domain`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2754508/1427878

Comment: I'm not sure that you can detect a page load from another tab or window. Off the top of my head, you can use `postMessage` in your popup script after the DOM has loaded there back to your parent page to indicate that it's DOM has been loaded. You can then postMessage as you have done in your handler from your parent page to the popup

Comment: Can you try `yo.document.readyState === "complete"`?

Comment: I tried `setTimeout(yo.postMessage.bind(this,"Hello mate", "*"), 5000);` as well. Unfortunately, it does not work and I do not know why.

Comment: Am i see this wrong, or you're trying to attach an event to another webpage,if the other page is yours, i would suggest you add some back-end api calls, and have the load event on the other page listening for those calls.